# React Router Component not Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-router, render

I've been working with React Router and trying to route my App.js and Car.js components together. I wrote {this.props.children} in those two components but it still isn't working. There is no where on my local host page that shows any indication of the Car.js component when I deploy my app.

Here's my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Login from './Login.js';
import Search from './Search.js';
import Message from './Message.js';
import Car from './Car.js';
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Login />
        <Search />
        <Message />
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter> 
                <Route path="/Car" component={Car}/>
                </BrowserRouter>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Car.js:

```
// Car page example 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Router, Route} from 'react-router';

class Car extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1> Cars page </h1>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Car;
```

Comment: there is no need of this.props.children and Route will be executed only when you visit the appropriate url

Comment: There is also no need for class components in this example.

Answer (score 1):

So you're going to want at least 2 routes unless /Cars is the only page in which case you don't need routing! :)

In this example the `Home` component will be displayed when your url is something like `http:/www.exmaple.com/`

The `Cars` component will be displayed when the url is `http:/www.exmaple.com/Cars`

```
const App = () => (
    <div>
        <Login />
        <Search />
        <Message />
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                // you're going to want a default view
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                // this will be displayed when your url has /Car at the end of it
                <Route path="/Car" component={Car} />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

If you don't want to have to manually type in the urls to change the views... You will have to include a `<Link />` or a `<NavLink />` that points to the respective view.

Try `<NavLink to="/Cars" />` and don't forget to add `{ ... NavLink ... } from "react-router-dom"` as well.

You might want to have a look at react-router [WEB documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy) over at [ReactTraining.com's react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/) page. They're the people who created and maintain `react-router`. Good documentation as well!